# How do I make critical shots?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

To unlock the *Untouchable* AR challenge, I have to "perform 3 Critical shots in one drone tank battle". What is a critical shot and how do I make one?

Comment: @Timelord64 I think Critical and Perfect shots are different.

Comment: The accepted answer for perfect shots details how I completed this AR, so I am doubtful.

Comment: 112madgamer makes a good point,however,I think these questions should be merged, given the similarity

Comment: @Timelord64 I've updated the other question to reference both critical and perfect shots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the vulcan (machine gun) to hit them right in the sensors. There's a cutscene where you discover that fact. You get a critical by blowing them up by hitting that spot (it'll show as a yellow critical thing on the left side above the combo meter).

You can also get a perfect hit by hitting that spot on the first shot. All using the vulcan of course.

The sensors are the blue lights on the right side of the smallest drones for example.